# Question about notation used to denote Hirzebruch surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, fiber-bundles

Is there a difference between $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n)$ and $\mathbb{P}\left(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n)\right)$?

I understand that the Hirzebruch surface $\mathbb{F}_n$ is defined as the (projectivization of the) bundle $\mathscr{O}\oplus \mathscr{O}(n)$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$. So what does the notation involving putting an overall $\mathbb{P}$ around this indicate?

Comment: The $\mathbb P$ denotes the projective space bundle associated to the vector bundle; you basically take local trivializations and projectivize the $2$-dimensional vector space factor to projective $1$-space.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBrevik. Do you mean that the $\mathbb{P}(..) $ denotes the total space of the bundle?

Comment: That's the notation I'm used to anyway. Hartshorne has an exercise or two on these things in, I believe Chapter II section 5.

Comment: Your definition of Hirzebruch surface is wrong. It is the projectivization of $\mathcal O \oplus \mathcal O(n)$, not the bundle itself (which is a quasi-projective threefold, not a projective surface).

Comment: Thank you @TabesBridges. I have corrected the post (it turns out to have been the very confusion that led to the post in the first place). I have a physics background and I'm ending up learning about these things in a somewhat haphazard way. Do you have any specific references in mind where I can learn some related math background? Thank you!

Comment: @leastaction : Did you try Miles Reid, "Chapters on algebraic surfaces" ? It is very nicely written.

Comment: Thank you @NicolasHemelsoet. I hadn't. I am looking at it now. Thanks for the reference!